# Pentaho Spoon: CROSS JOIN on 2 streams

Tags: join, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, cross-join, pentaho-data-integration

I have main stream that has some fields and hundreds of thousands of records.

I created a Table Input to just query the max value of a date column. It brings 1 unique record.

Now I need to do some kind of CROSS join this Table Input into the main stream, and add this new column into ts columns set. There's no ON clause, all records will have the same value for that column.

I tried using Merge Join, but instead of adding the value to all records it added an extra record to the stream. This extra record has null on all fields and the date value on the new field, while all original records have the new field as null.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a "Join Rows (cartesian product)" step for this case.

Comment: I would go with the Join Rows as well, being the most efficient way to do this. Just make sure you choose the large data stream as the "main step to read from"

Answer (score 1):

you could use a stream lookup step. You would just need to make sure your main stream has a constant lookup value (`add constant` step right before the stream lookup) and add the same constant value in a new column to your query stream. The stream lookup should find the query result and add it to your main stream.